# What information do i get to display about my user when i choose google federated sign in with firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I created a Google federated sign in with my website. It serves as a layer of authentication so I have only my select crowd of users I'm targeting. How and what information do I get from the user when they sign in?

Answer (score 2):

As for what information that you get about the user, you can see list of available properties and information that you will retrieve in [the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.User).

But for your question about how to white-list a "select crowd": what you can do is to create database security rules that are inspecting the [auth object](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#authtoken) and limiting access based on their email addresses.

### Realtime database

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "(auth.token.email == 'mybuddy@gmail.com' || auth.token.email == 'anotherfriend@gmail.com')",
    ".write": "(auth.token.email == 'mybuddy@gmail.com' || auth.token.email == 'anotherfriend@gmail.com')"
  }
}
```

### Firestore

```
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if isWhiteListedUser();
    }
  }

  function isWhiteListedUser () {
    return request.auth.token.email == 'mybuddy@gmail.com'
    || request.auth.token.email == 'anotherfriend@gmail.com';
  }
}
```

### White-listing a whole domain of users

If your Google signins should be restricted to a certain domain of Gsuite accounts you can also just check that [their email addresses are ending with the domain](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/security/database/#endswithsubstring) that you want to allow using your app.

`".read": "auth.token.identifier.endsWith('@company.com')"`

Comment: "Links to external resources are encouraged, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline" In this case, the link may not help as the OP is asking *I have only my select crowd of users I'm targeting* to which having user object properties won't help target a select crowd. It will only tell them about *this* user, not other users. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Comment: My current rule `if request.auth.token.email == 'user1@mydomain.com'` is working. But not `if request.auth.token.email.endsWith('@mydomain.com')` nor `"auth.token.identifier.endsWith('@mydomain.com')"`. I'm getting `Missing or insufficient permissions` error

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to know for sure? ...Use your browsers Developr Tools (cntrl + shift + i) to browse the user object.

Inside your `.onAuthStateChanged` observer put `console.dir(firebase.auth().currentUser)`.

Sign in and then check your dev tools console. You will now have an expandable Firebase User object containing anything and everything you are given by Firebase about that user.